# If I create a secondary world to boost my first, will I keep items from the secondary world after deleting it?

Tags: terraria

I have 4 worlds already and wanted to delete one, all worlds I've gotten items that I brought back to my first world. I'm just wondering if I delete a world would the items I received will stay?

Comment: You could put the items in your pocket and transfer them to another world but AFAIK deleting a world deletes everything in it, including chests and their contents.

Answer (score 5):

Items within a world are self-contained, and unaffected by the deletion of their source. Items held by a character are also self-contained, and are unaffected by the deletion of their source. If you delete a world, all items within that world will be deleted, but a character holding items from that world will keep their items. The same can be said for another world containing items obtained from the deleted world; **all** items within the world will remain (except for those held by characters).

*tl;dr* **Yes.**

Edit: The contents of piggy banks and safes are character specific, can be accessed from any world using the same character, and remain attached to the character regardless of a world being deleted. Thanks, Ben Ong.

Comment: Add on point: Piggy Bank and Safe are considered personal, those items will stay with the character when the world is deleted too